# How can I conditionally designate an active quote in csquotes.cfg?

Tags: conditionals, csquotes, active-characters

How can I conditionally designate an active quote in `csquotes.cfg` so that no error is produced if the same character is made into an active quote in the `.cfg` and the document's preamble?

I have the following effective code in `csquotes.cfg`:

```
\MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}
\MakeAutoQuote*{“}{”}

\endinput
```

Is it possible to activate this code at the end of the preamble and only if the `\MakeAutoQuote` and `\MakeAutoQuote*` have not already been set for these characters?

That is, I would like to be able to compile the following document notwithstanding `csquotes.cfg`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}
\MakeAutoQuote*{“}{”}
\begin{document}
‘abc’
\end{document}
```

as well as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
‘abc’
\end{document}
```

Comment: By conditionally, do you mean you would be willing to use `\if`s? That is, wrap the `\Make...`s in the `.cfg` in a conditional, and then add a `\newif` statement before the document class? Or are you looking for a cleverer version of `\MakeAutoQuote`?

Comment: @jon I'm hoping for a test I can do in the `.cfg` which does not require altering the document preamble e.g. an existing `\if` of some kind, so I don't need to add it in the document preamble.

Comment: I suspected as much. So, something like a `\ProvideAutoQuote` command....

Comment: @jon Exactly. I tried looking at the source for `csquotes` and, after that, figured I'd ask here :(.

Comment: @cfr I posted a present for your great achievement. Congratulations for your 100K!

Comment: @egreg It isn't as if I *did* anything, so I'm not sure it counts as an `achievement` of any kind at all. Really, it just happened to me. If I did anything, it was certainly an accident!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon seeing `\MakeAutoQuote` or `\MakeAutoQuote*`, `csquotes` defines `\csq@string@<number>` for both arguments in a suitable way. The `<number>` represents the decimal ASCII codes of the UTF-8 representation of the character, separated by periods if multibyte.

However, the package already provides the infrastructure for the conversion.

```
\begin{filecontents}{csquotes.cfg}
\MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}
\MakeAutoQuote*{“}{”}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\makeatletter
\def\ConditionalMakeAutoQuote#1#{%
  \def\cfr@star{#1}\CMAQ@
}
\def\CMAQ@#1#2{%
  \csq@ifutfchar{#1}
    {\csq@ifvalidutf{#1}
       {\ifcsundef{csq@string@\csq@number{#1}}
          {\expandafter\MakeAutoQuote\cfr@star{#1}{#2}}
          {}
       }%
       {\csq@err@utf}}
    {\csq@ifvalidchar{#1}
       {\ifcsundef{csq@string@\number`#1}
          {\expandafter\MakeAutoQuote\cfr@star{#1}{#2}}
          {}}%
       {\csq@err@char}}}
\makeatother

\ConditionalMakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}
\ConditionalMakeAutoQuote*{“}{”}

\begin{document}

‘abc’

“abc”

‘abc “abc” abc’

\end{document}
```

I get the same result, namely

[image]

with or without the `csquotes.cfg` file, which is read just after `csquotes.def`, so before any possible definition of quoting characters in the document.

Comment: Thank you! I wish I understood this. I understand it just enough to figure out how to modify it very slightly for my purposes, but I don't understand it. However, the slightly adapted version works OK in the `.cfg` file, which is good. (I don't want this in the document itself for various reasons related to teaching.) Thanks very much again.

Comment: @cfr I don't fully understand it either.  I took the code whereby the error message is issued, in case the shorthand is already defined, and modified it to do `\MakeAutoQuote` if possible.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Since nobody seems to be biting, I did a little more investigation and came up with the following for `csquotes.cfg`.

```
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \DeleteQuotes
  \MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}%
  \MakeAutoQuote*{“}{”}%
}

\endinput
```

However, this means that I cannot override my defaults in the preamble of a particular document because it works by zapping the existing definitions - whatever they happen to be - and then adding the definitions I want as defaults.

This *is* compatible with both of the MWEs I posted in the question i.e. both will compile.

However, it is not very satisfactory. I would prefer to *add* to document-level definitions, if possible, or to *do nothing*, otherwise. I did try checking whether the cat codes for the characters are active or not, but I couldn't get this to work, probably because I know so little about managing cat codes.